# Перегрузка методов, продвижение типов JAVA

Tags: java, ооп, function-overloading

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
public class OverloadTest {
    void print(Integer i){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
    void print(long i){
        System.out.println("long");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverloadTest overloadTest = new OverloadTest();
        overloadTest.print(3);
    }
}
```

Будет вызван метод, принимающий тип long, т.к. продвижение типов следующее:

```
int > long > float > double > Integer > Number > Object
```

Рассмотрим тот же самый пример, только в качестве параметра передадим массив переменной длины того же типа:

```
public class OverloadTest {
    void print(Integer...i){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
    void print(long...i){
        System.out.println("long");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverloadTest overloadTest = new OverloadTest();
        overloadTest.print(3);
    }
}
```

Данный код завершится ошибкой времени выполнения:

```
Error:(11, 21) java: reference to print is ambiguous
both method print(java.lang.Integer...) in OverloadTest and method print(long...) in OverloadTest match
```

Почему теперь вызов неоднозначен и правила продвижения типов для массива переменной длины не работают?

Comment: Потому что приведения типов не работаю с массивами примитивных типов?

Comment: Если определить (int...i) и (Integer...i) и передать в качестве параметра 3 компилятор поругается, что непонятно какой из них выбрать. В таком случае почему тогда при long...i и Integer...i не выбрать оболочку?

Comment: И если оно действительно не работает, как бы было возможно вызвать такой НЕ перегруженный метод void print(Integer...i) и передать туда число? Все же он автоупакуется. То же самое с (long...i), компилятор поймет что мы имели ввиду long даже без постфикса l - 3l.

Comment: @Donatello методы с переменным количеством аргументов - это синтаксический сахар. Ещё до компиляции `long...i` будет преобразовано в `long[] i`, а приведение типов между массивом примитивов и массивом ссылок невозможно.

Comment: согласно [jls-15.12.2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4) оба метода подходят, т.к. аргумент можно преобразовать и в `Integer` и в `long`, при этом ни один из методов не является более специфичным, поскольку `Integer` и `long` не связаны отношением супертипа.

Comment: @zRrr большое спасибо за ёмкое разъяснение

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перечисляемый тип не указан в списке продвижения, поэтому компилятор определяет, что оба метода подходят для вызова и выдает ошибку.

Comment: Я попробую резюмировать все советы в одно сообщение:

Comment: Если у нас есть перегруженные методы, которые в качестве параметра принимают массив переменной длины, то будет вызван тот метод, тип массива которого будет точно совпадать с типом переданных элементов. Если же точного совпадения нет( например передаем int i и массив int..i), тогда будет вызван метод, тип которого позволяет хранить в себе переданных тип. Если же таких методов несколько, то продвижение типов работать не будет, и данный вызов завершится ошибкой времени выполнения, поскольку невозможно будет выполнить однозначный выбор между перегруженными методами.